# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file d igest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ant

I have an application that when run in the IDE (Netbeans 8) works fine. The program makes use of 4 external .jar libraries. It also has a virtual machine argument pointing to a DLL. When I try to execute the .jar from the command line I get an error. This leads me to believe that there is a classpath issue.

This is the error itself:

```
C:\Users\piuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GameTrakaDesktopClient\dist>java -jar
GameTrakaDesktopClient.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for    
Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at gametrakadesktopclient.MainMenuUI.main(MainMenuUI.java:242)

C:\Users\piuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GameTrakaDesktopClient\dist>
```

Comment: Did you sign your jar?

Comment: No I don't believe any of them are signed. Is that something I am supposed to do? I thought I could just leave them unsigned. If so please can you point me in the direction of some references to understand signing of jars?

Comment: It's not something you need to do, but you would get this error if you did sign a JAR and then modified it afterwards.

Comment: I didn't sign my JAR which is why I am pulling my hair out. It executes fine in Netbeans though so I think I must be doing something wrong with classpaths etc..

Comment: Does your JAR have any .SF files in the META-INF folder? Also, did you edit the manifest after creating the JAR or did you create the JAR with the manifest in it?

Comment: There are no .SF files in the META-INF folders. Netbeans was not automatically regenerating the manifest when I ran clean+build so I manually edited it's contents.

Comment: EDIT:

It seems that there are signatures on some of the other libraries that I am using. The weird part is that it works in Netbeans, but not in the command line. I must be doing something wrong with configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I have used a workaround to get around this problem because I couldn't figure out a solution. I opened all of the JAR files that my application depends on and removed the META-INF/.DSA and META-INF/.SF files